# Divide Menu into Separate Menus and Display them Side by Side

Tags: menus

I'm having problems saving a large menu. I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error. I'm using WP 3.1. I use a HostGator dedicated Linux server and the Superb theme.

I have  a menu with 4 main headings each with dropdown menus. Is it possible to divide my menu into "4 menus" and display them side by side? The Superb theme has one menu area. Is this possible? If so, how can I do that?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: I know it's not an answer to your questions, but if you're able to upgrade to WordPress 3.2 I believe the menu-handling is much improved. Another option is to increase the PHP memory limits so saving doesn't time out. Here's one way to do that in your wp-config file: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP Best of luck!

Comment: Hi FriendlyWP, Thank you for your message. I upgraded, but unfortunately, the problem wasn't solved. I'd like to try to increase the PHP memory limit as you suggested. But, I'm not sure I understand the instructions. Do I simply plop tis define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M'); in the wp-config.php file? Thank you!

Comment: Yep, pretty much. That might not work depending on your web host, though; here are 5 different ways to try to increase the memory limit: http://www.dailyblogging.org/wordpress/increase-wordpress-memory-limit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. I used the Gecka Submenu Pro plugin. (No, they didn't pay me to post).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your host and/or check your error log, you might have to turn on more error reporting depending on what level it is set at, it could be any number of things including memory allocation.

To have multiple menus you can use `register_nav_menus`
Reference:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

To add them to your template you use `wp_nav_menu`
Reference:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Hi Wyck, Thank you for the help. I had HostGator change the memory and timeout limits without any luck. Apparently, this menu save bug is a known issue and WP is working on a solution-- probably it'll be fixed in 3.3.